# How Turning List into Class Object for Flask Templating

Tags: python, class, loops, flask, jinja2

How to I turn a list of lists into a class that I can call for each object like `foo.bar.spam`?

list of lists:

`information =[['BlueLake1','MO','North','98812'], ['BlueLake2','TX','West','65343'], ['BlueLake3','NY','sales','87645'],['RedLake1','NY','sales','58923'],['RedLake2','NY','sales','12644'],['RedLake3','KY','sales','32642']]`

This would be to create variables for a very large html table using jinja2 templating in Flask.

I would want to be able to to do something like this:

```
{% for x in information %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>Via: {{x.location}} | Loop: {{x.region}}</td>
        <td>{{x.idcode}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

There will be other uses then just this one template with this information, hence why I want it to be a callable class to use in other places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Info = namedtuple('Info', ['name', 'location', 'region', 'idcode'])
>>>
>>> information =[
...     ['BlueLake1','MO','North','98812'],
...     ['BlueLake2','TX','West','65343'],
...     ['BlueLake3','NY','sales','87645'],
...     ['RedLake1','NY','sales','58923'],
...     ['RedLake2','NY','sales','12644'],
...     ['RedLake3','KY','sales','32642']
... ]
>>> [Info(*x) for x in information]
[Info(name='BlueLake1', location='MO', region='North', idcode='98812'),
 Info(name='BlueLake2', location='TX', region='West', idcode='65343'),
 Info(name='BlueLake3', location='NY', region='sales', idcode='87645'),
 Info(name='RedLake1', location='NY', region='sales', idcode='58923'),
 Info(name='RedLake2', location='NY', region='sales', idcode='12644'),
 Info(name='RedLake3', location='KY', region='sales', idcode='32642')]
```

Comment: Using namedtuples is a nice shortcut in this case. Like it.

Comment: Okay, and then how would I get this to be able to do `info = [Info(*x) for x in information]` `for x in info: print x.name`? I tried this and it just prints out `<property object at 0x02592480>`

Comment: @BilliAm, I don't understand what you mean. See this: http://asciinema.org/a/12893

Comment: I deleted all of my code and pasted your's in and it worked. Don't know what was going on there. Apologies.

Also by the way, that asciinema.org site is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most common way is to put each of the records into a dict

```
info = []
for r in information:
    record = dict(name=r[0], location=r[1], region=r[2], idcode=r[3])
    info.append(record)
```

Jinja2 then allows you to use x.name etc to access the properties exactly as you do in your example.

```
{% for x in info %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>Via: {{x.location}} | Loop: {{x.region}}</td>
        <td>{{x.idcode}}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

NOTE this way of indexing into the data (x.name) is a jinja2 specific shortcut (though it's stolen from django templates, which probably stole it from something else).

Within python itself you'd have to do:

```
for x in info:
    print(x['name'])
    # x.name will throw an error since name isn't an 'attribute' within x
    # x['name'] works because 'name' is a 'key' that we added to the dict
```

Comment: So then how would I access each dictionary item like x.name? I tryt this and then `for x in info: print x.name` and I get `'dict' object has no attribute 'name'` I am still not seeing how I get there.

Comment: Indeed, it's a shortcut that jinja2 added to allow you more easily access the contents of a dict in your templates. I'll add the details to the answer for you. Since it sounds as though this is unfamiliar terrain (dicts are a core building block of the language), I'd highly recommend you read some of the docs to see how to use them - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries - actually, I'd highly recommend going through that whole page. It's a great overview of the common ways of storing data within python.

Comment: Awesome! Thats what I was looking for.